# Error with image.float.colorize

Tags: image, lua, torch

image package has a function called colorize which can be invoked using image.float.colorize. What is the dimension of the arguments of the function colorize.
In my case,

```
image=require 'image'
-- input: greyscale image of type FloatTensor of size 1x50x50
colorimage=image.float.colorize(input)
```

The above gives the following error:

```
[string "colorimage=image.float.colorize(input)"]:1: bad argument #2 to 'colorize' (torch.FloatTensor expected, got userdata)
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'colorize'
[string "colorimage=image.float.colorize(input)"]:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
/home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:679: in function 'repl'
.../torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:204: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x00405e90
```

Any help regarding the above would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/c4f41c3156924a7509f9b7b3b5dcb1fa6e3b2f79/generic/image.c#L2037) `colorize` takes 3 arguments- `output`, `input` and `colormap`. You can see an example in the `init.lua` [file](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/5aa18819b6a7b44751f8a858bd232d1c07b67985/init.lua#L2147).

Comment: Thank you @kingJulian. I found that my purpose can be met using image.y2jet. However outputimg=image.y2jet(inputimg) gives error as
/home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:2147: bad argument #2 to 'colorize' (out of range at /home/torch/pkg/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensor.c:882)

Comment: I think this error indicates that you are still using `colorize` somewhere in your program. Also, check [this](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/colorspace.md) to see more details about `y2jet`.